# оператор lock ()

Tags: c#

Почему оператор lock () предназначен для приема только параметров ссылочного типа?

Comment: Потому что в значимом типе нет места для хранения флага блокировки

Comment: @АндрейNOP ответом мож?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, а в ссылочном оно где? :)

Comment: @Grundy, где-то среди прочего?

Comment: @tym32167, а у меня нету достоверной информации только наитие и интуиция

Comment: @АндрейNOP ну а мне кажется, что при передаче value типа в `Monitor.Enter(..)` значение переменной будет скопировано и залочится на копию, а не на оригинал, что делает всю конструкцию бесполензной )

Comment: [Why can't we lock on a value type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8267323/2881286)

Comment: @tym32167, по-моему у нас где-то был уже вопрос про это

Comment: @Grundy а, ну да, боксинг же ещё. Я хз, не помню такого вопроса на РуСО